# SSL and NIO Non-blocking Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, nio, nonblocking

How do you recommend making a highly scalable SSL client?

Currently, I'm using plain `Socket`s to connect to the Apple APNS server which requires a non-HTTP SSL sockets.  I considered using the NIO library, but it is lacking a `SSLSocketChannel`, and I couldn't find a good library or a smooth tutorial on how to roll out your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look at Mina SSLFilter,

http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/filter/ssl/SslFilter.html

If you don't want use Mina for some reason, you can also look at BouncyCastle JCE, whose SSL handler is easy to hook up with any stream,

http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/tls/TlsProtocolHandler.html